# <a> tag concatonates current url to href value in django

Tags: html, django

Im building an app where users can enter their twitter, fb and ig account links to their profiles. After they have submitted these urls to the profile form my django app save them to db and later on these values should be populated in the profile page as  tags as such.

```
<div class="gap-3 mt-3 icons d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    {% if object.twitter_link %}
                        <a href="{{ object.twitter_link }}"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span></a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if object.fb_link %}
                        <a href="{{ object.fb_link }}"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></span></a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if object.ig_link %}
                        <a href="{{ object.ig_link }}"><span><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></span></a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

I noticed that the  tag values are not the same as in the href attribute. For example these are the actual values of the href attribute and the corresponding  tag values.

{{ object.twitter_link }} = 'weeeee' --> https://currentpageurl.com/weeeee
{{ object.fb_link }} = 'www.facebook.com' --> https://currentpageurl.com/www.facebook.com
{{ object.ig_link }} = 'https://www.instagram.com/instagram/' --> https://www.instagram.com/instagram/

The  tag generated the value that is inside href attribute only in case when the link had an https prefix. In all other cases it concatenated the current page url with the value inside the href attribute.

How can I avoid this behaviour and make the  tag show only what is actually in the href attribute?